# R Markdown, numbering not showing for figure captions in HTML and Word

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am putting together an R Markdown document in HTML, and I have the following YAML:

```
---
title: "R Markdown Example"
author: "Me"
date: "October 30, 2017"
output:
  html_document:
     fig_width: 7
     fig_height: 6
     fig_caption: true
     code_folding: "show"
---
```

I am trying to insert a figure with auto-numbered caption with the following code:

````
```{r, fig.cap="Figure caption \\label{fig_1}"}
plot(mtcars$hp, mtcars$mpg)
```
````

But the caption number won't show up. When I try to reference the image in the text

```
(Figure \ref{fig_1})
```

I just get:

(Figure )

I have the same problem. This only happens for Word and HTML outputs, so I think I may be using LaTeX documentation instead of the proper input for these types. I've tried a lot of the different recommendations for figure captions, but I can't seem to get any of it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bookdown::html_document2` format.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap='test plot'}
plot(pressure)
```

\@ref(fig:pressure)
````

[image]

Comment: That worked, but is there any way to do it without the Bookdown package? (Just through base R-markdown)

Comment: @Christine, there is no cross-referencing without in base `rmarkdown`/`knitr`. The package author, *Yihui Xie*, built this output format because that feature was lacking.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with word docs? It works fine for HTML, but not word for me

Answer (score 6):

I needed to output to Word to adhere to a journal that only accepted Word...  So I ended up using the `captioner` package.  This should also work with html and pdf.

```
library(captioner)
fig_nums <- captioner()
```

In my r chunk I put my plot code and then the caption comes directly after the chunk in ticks, using the `fig_nums` function ``:

````
```{r}
plot(pressure)
```

 `r fig_nums("pressure-plot", "pressure against temperature")`
````

It looks like this in the Word output:
[image]

Then I can refer to it in text like this:

> As you can see from the nice visualisation in `r fig_nums("pressure-plot", display = "cite")` the pressure rises as
> temperature rises.

This will show as:

> As you can see from the nice visualisation in Figure 1 the pressure rises as
> temperature rises

Be sure to run the first time you use, and check-out for more info:

```
install.packages("captioner")
vignette("using_captioner")
```

Comment: Connected question: how do you center-align captions using the captionizer package?

Comment: @TomHengl - if you're doing this in Word, I think you'd need to do that in your Word template rather that your Markdown document.  There's info on creating such a template here: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html

Comment: It seems like there's a missing step in the instructions (although you do point to the vignette for more details) - you need to create `fig_nums` using `fig_nums <- captioner()`

Comment: You're absolutely right @Miff - just edited to show this.  Also could do e.g. `table_nums <- captioner(prefix = "Table")` if one wanted to do table captions.